# Adding CSS class to a Lightning subcomponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, css

Today, I'm faced with this problem: I have a button in a parent component that should open a modal dialog in a subcomponent, but when I add a class to show my modal dialog it doesn't work.
Here is the **parent's component code**:

```
<aura:component access="GLOBAL">        
    ...     
    <lightning:button class="signerButtons" tabindex="{!index}" label="" iconName="standard:people" iconPosition="left" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.showOppmodal}"/>        
    ...     
    <c:OrganizeEnvelopeModalWindow/>    
</aura:component>
```

Parent's **JS controller** code:

```
   showOppmodal: function(component, event, helper) {
         //Toggle CSS styles for opening Modal
        helper.toggleClass(component,'backdrop','slds-backdrop--');
        helper.toggleClass(component,'modaldialog','slds-fade-in-');
    },
```

Parent's **Helper** code:

```
  toggleClass: function(component,componentId,className) {
        var modal = component.find(componentId);
        $A.util.removeClass(modal,className+'hide');
        $A.util.addClass(modal,className+'open');
    },
```

Lastly, the **subcomponent** code:

```
<aura:component access="GLOBAL" >
    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aura:id="modaldialog">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Firmatari</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <div class="c-container">
                    <p>Hello</p>

                 </div>             
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open" aura:id="backdrop"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Maybe, I missed to know something about the scope of the parents and subcomponents.

How can I resolve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` method only finds components that are direct children. One way to fix that would be:

```
<c:OrganizeEnvelopeModalWindow aura:id="modal"/>

showOppmodal: function(component, event, helper) {
    //Toggle CSS styles for opening Modal
    var modal = component.find("modal");
    helper.toggleClass(modal,'backdrop','slds-backdrop--');
    helper.toggleClass(modal,'modaldialog','slds-fade-in-');
},
```

The way I display a modal is to add the class `slds-fade-in-open` to the modal and `slds-backdrop--open` to the backdrop.

Probably a better way to organize this is to use an attribute to show/hide the modal:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="show" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <div class="{! 'slds-modal slds-modal--large ' + (v.show ? 'slds-fade-in-open' : '') }">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="{! 'slds-backdrop ' + (v.show ? 'slds-backdrop--open' : '') }">
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

so the containing component doesn't have to reach inside but instead can directly set the `show` attribute.